Spring-boot bean validation custom message for generated bean
I'm trying to add validation to a bean so I can verify its state before persisting it.
The class for the bean that requires validation is generated by the openapi-generator-maven-plugin plugin from an OpenAPI contract.
As the contract contains restrictions, they Jakarta constraint annotations are present on the generated bean as well. It looks like this (simplified):
public class User {

    @NotNull
    private String name;
}

I added a messages.properties file in the src/main/resources folder with the following content:
jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=global not null error message

If I then execute the jakarta.validation.Validator.validate(user), the interpolated message matches the configured one. But this configuration applies to all properties that are null, while I only want to apply this to this specific property.
Is there a way I can configure the bean validator to return a specific message through configuration, without having to modify the bean (as it is generated)? I tried to add the following to the messages.properties (suggested by AI):
org.company.User.name.NotNull=Username cannot be null

But the validation framework just seems to ignore this?
All help is appreciated.

You should set up the message field of the annotation.
@NotNull(message = "{org.company.User.name.NotNull}")
private String name;


I'm sure this would work, but since the class is generated, I'm not able to modify it (directly)

You could use https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/file-post-processing or create a custom generator extending that one.
